# How was the starting vertex chosen in this solution?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, solution-verification

From Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications, 3ed, chapter 11 p. 799-800:

[image: prim]

The solution given only shows a graph starting from vertex `b`.  I wonder if this is arbitrarily chosen, because there are 3 edges of weight `1` and 6 vertices to pick from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prim's algorithm produces a correct minimum spanning tree *regardless of which vertex it starts from*. The choice of $b$ was entirely arbitrary.

Comment: Are you saying it would give the same tree if the other 5 vertices were chosen?

Comment: @J.Doe Not necessarily the same tree, but the same weight.